# How to access instance of SPTCoreAudioController from SPTAudioStreamingController?

Tags: ios, delegates, core-audio, spotify

How can I access the instance of the `SPTCoreAudioController` that is associated with my instance of a `SPTAudioStreamingController`?

I need to assign a `SPTCoreAudioControllerDelegate` so that I may handle `coreAudioController:didOutputAudioOfDuration` in order to, as you say, "keep track of how much audio has been played back for progress indicators and so on".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve it from wherever you put it. If you initialise like this…

```
self.coreAudio = [MyAwesomeCoreAudioController new];
self.streaming = [[SPTAudioStreamingController alloc]
                      initWithCompanyName:@"DanCorp"
                                  appName:@"MyApp"
                          audioController:self.coreAudio];
```

…you can access it with `self.coreAudio`.

Comment: Your solution produces the following error: `No visible @interface for 'SPTAudioStreamingController' declares the selector 'initWithCompanyName:appName:audioController:`    Please advise.

Comment: We're using spotify ios sdk beta-2

Comment: Look in `SPTAudioStreamingController.h` for the method definitions. Beta 2 certainly has it there.